# Convert from multi-dimensional array to json Object in javascript to iterate in table (grid) on angular 8 app

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

Actual Output :

```
[["Name","Age","Location","Gender"],["Mary",28,"KY","F"],["Jonathan",34,"NJ","M"],["Kevin",31,"CA","M"]]
```

Expected output :

```
[
  {
    "Name":"Mary",
    "Age":28,
    "Location":"KY" ,
    "Gender":"F"
  },
  {
    "Name":"Jonathan",
    "Age":34,
    "Location":"NJ",
    "Gender":"M"
  },
  {
    "Name":"Kevin",
    "Age":31,
    "Location":"CA",
    "Gender":"M"
  }
]
```

Please help me with this. So that I can iterate in table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const input = [["Name", "Age", "Location", "Gender"], ["Mary", 28, "KY", "F"], ["Jonathan", 34, "NJ", "M"], ["Kevin", 31, "CA", "M"]];
const keys = input[0];
const output = input.slice(1).map(entry => {
    const retVal = {};
    keys.forEach((key, index) => {
        retVal[key] = entry[index];
    });
    return retVal;
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Destructure the keys from the values. Map the array of values (`vals`), and use `Object.fromEntries()` to create an object by mapping each values sub-array (`varr`), and combining with the respective key to create an array of [key, value] entries.

to create an object from the values and the keys:

```js
const objecttify = ([keys, ...vals]) => // destructure the keys and an array of values
  vals.map(varr => // map the values
    Object.fromEntries( // convert the entries to an object
      varr.map((v, i) => [keys[i], v]) // create the entries by combining a value with it's respective key
    )
  )

const arr = [["Name","Age","Location","Gender"],["Mary",28,"KY","F"],["Jonathan",34,"NJ","M"],["Kevin",31,"CA","M"]]

const result = objecttify(arr)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation.